# Pytest - raise exception in for loop

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I try raise exception in pytest when battery run out from device when calculator count 100x times.
class:

```
class Calculator:
def __init__(self, battery: int = 100, filename=None):
    self.battery = battery
    self.filename = filename
    self.check_battery()

def check_battery(self):
    if self.battery <= 0:
        raise NoBatteryError("The battery has run out")

def add(self, *args):
    self.check_battery()
    self.battery -= 1
    result_add = 0

    for number_to_add in args:
        result_add += number_to_add
    return result_add


class NoBatteryError(Exception):
    pass
```

Pytest:

```
def test_battery_by_calculate_100x_times(calc):
    # Given
    for iteration in range(1, 103):
        value = 2
        result = calc.add(value, value)
        expected_value = value + value
        try:
            result == expected_value
        except NoBatteryError:
            assert True
```

Output:

```
FAILED test_electronic_device_calculator.py::test_battery_by_calculate_100x_times - electronic_devices.calculator.NoBatteryError: The battery has run out
=========1 failed, 29 passed in 0.20s =======
```

Simple test like:

```
def test_check_battery_should_raise_no_battery_error(calc):
    calc.battery = 0
    with pytest.raises(NoBatteryError):
        calc.check_battery()
```

work for me. I try use also in for loop with pytest.raises(NoBatteryError) - but my function also don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it should looks like that but works:

```
def test_battery_by_calculate_100x_times(calc):
for iteration in range(0, 102):
    value = 2
    try:
        calc.add(value, value)
    except NoBatteryError:
        assert True
```